# When i refresh page, my application continue inserting data into database Yii2

Tags: php, database, yii2

**Theres the action**

```
public function actionEfetuarPedidoReserva($idQuarto){
    $modelPedidoReservaQuarto = new PedidoReservaQuarto();
    $modelPedidoReserva = new PedidoReserva();
    $model = new ComodidadesExtra();
    $modelListaComodidades = new ListaComodidadesQuarto();
    $modelPedidoReservaQuarto->quartoId = $idQuarto;

    if($modelPedidoReservaQuarto->save()){
        $modelPedidoReserva->nPessoas = 2;
        $modelPedidoReserva->preco = 70.00;
        $modelPedidoReserva->reservaQuartoId = $modelPedidoReservaQuarto->id;
        $modelPedidoReserva->userInfoId = Yii::$app->user->id;

        if($modelPedidoReserva->save()){
            $model->pedidoReservaId = $modelPedidoReserva->id;

            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
                return $this->redirect(['efetuar-pedido-reserva', 'idQuarto' => $idQuarto]);
            }

            return $this->render('../comodidades-extra/create', [
                'model' => $model, 'modelLista' => $modelListaComodidades
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

When i refresh page, it add the last pedidoreservaid inserted + 1;
i Would like to know if am i doing it the right way.

Comment: How is this action triggered?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Because you are saving the model every time you call the action. Why you first save the model and then load the data coming from POST?

Comment: Because I need to insert data into a table, and that table is pending from the data of the other. For example, first i need to insert data on PedidoReservaQuarto and then insert into PedidoReserva

Comment: So you have to rethink the logic of your controller, because in this way everytime you call  this action you save +1

Comment: ok thanks, I'll try to find solution

Comment: show your form, what do you save from it? Do you have only `$model` post?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you create new instance of `ComodidadesExtra` each time when you call `$model = new ComodidadesExtra();`. Yii2 consider it as new independent row and you need to tell Yii2 that you should take existing row instead, using:

```
$model = ComodidadesExtra::find()
    ->where(['pedidoReservaId' => $modelPedidoReserva->id])
    ->one();
```

And your controller should look like:

```
if($modelPedidoReserva->save()){
            if(null===($model = ComodidadesExtra::find()->where(['pedidoReservaId' => $modelPedidoReserva->id])
    ->one())) { 
                $model = new ComodidadesExtra(); 
            }
            $model->pedidoReservaId = $modelPedidoReserva->id;

            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
                return $this->redirect(['efetuar-pedido-reserva', 'idQuarto' => $idQuarto]);
            }

            return $this->render('../comodidades-extra/create', [
                'model' => $model, 'modelLista' => $modelListaComodidades
            ]);
        }
```